# Custom validator control occupying space even though display set to dynamic

Tags: asp.net, html

Why is the custom validator control occupying height even though it is set to display equals dynamic:

```
<tr>
    <td style="min-height: 0px;">
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFiscalFromyear" runat="server" Style="width: 160px;" ErrorMessage="From fiscal year required" ForeColor="Green" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ClientValidationFunction="fncFromFiscalYear">Required</asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
    <td style="min-height: 0px;">
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvFiscalToyear" Style="width: 160px;" runat="server" ErrorMessage="To fiscal year required" ForeColor="Green" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="fncToFiscalYear">Required</asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is inside table tag. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Display="Dynamic"` is probably set out of function by the "Required" you're showing as content of the Customvalidator.

Comment: You mean display=dynamic (i.e. it's an HTML property NOT a CSS property).

Comment: You're of course right and I changed it in my original post, thank you