# RequiredFieldValidator taking space despite Display=Dynamic

Tags: asp.net

I have read in multiple sources that in order for a RequiredFieldValidator not to take space before there's an error message the property "Display" has to be set to "Dynamic" like here:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator27" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="dayDropDownList" ErrorMessage="Day is required*" ForeColor="Red" 
InitialValue="Day" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I've tried a million times on different controls but my requiredFieldValidators are still taking place no matter what. The only relevant question I found was this one - [Custom validator control occupying space even though display set to dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908081/custom-validator-control-occupying-space-even-though-display-set-to-dynamic), but I found the answer to be very vague, it didn't say what needs to be done to make it work.

Any help please?

Comment: Normally it doesn't with `dynamic`. Maybe there is a CSS class that does something with the `<span>` element of the validator?

Comment: That's not the case.